# Accidentally Moved Download Folder while using mv command in Windows

Tags: windows-10

Moved Downloads folder to C:\Users\val folder (where it already resides) instead of moving file from the Downloads folder to C:\Users\val in Windows 10. On clicking the Downloads folder in Quick Access I get an error message saying no such folder exists. I checked for solutions [here](https://superuser.com/a/1043626/576705) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/1043598/576705).Tried these 2 solutions but does not work.

Comment: Have you tried to simply move the folder back.

Comment: i moved it to the same location using mv command

Answer (score 2):

Finally could resolve the issue. Hope it helps someone if they come across a similar issue.

1. Right-click the Downloads Folder.
2. Select Properties.
3. Select Location Tab.
4. Click Restore Default. A new Downloads folder will be created.
5. Copy all your download folder contents to the new Downloads and you can then delete the old Downloads folder.