# Can't get back my downloads after moving it D:\ drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, command-line, windows-8, download

I am having the exact same problem as this person here:

[Win10 - Accidentally moved my downloads folder to D:\, can't seem to revert or change](https://superuser.com/questions/1043594/win10-accidentally-moved-my-downloads-folder-to-d-cant-seem-to-revert-or-c/1043626#1043626?newreg=2f3783ad6abe4c16b2374f8aac6a4de1)

I accidentally made my downloads and my D:\ drive a single entity.
The solution worked for him but *not for me*:

> I actually had to do this in 3 places! `User Shell Folders/` and `Shell Folders/` (2 registries in here!). After that I was able to move the folder but I still had an issue: The new downloads folder was hidden and a system folder so I couldn't navigate to it normally. Had to do `attrib -r "D:\Downloads" -s -h` in a command prompt and then `attrib -r "D:\Downloads" +s` to give it the download folder icon back :) - [Joe Shanahan](https://superuser.com/users/561760/joe-shanahan)

I have done all the steps for `Regedit.exe`, but it isn't working for me.
The user seems to have already found his own way but I have tried doing `attrib -r "D:\Downloads" -s -h`  in command prompt and then `attrib -r "D:\Downloads" +s` like he did, but my download folder isn't back.

Here's a screenshot of what shows up.

[image]

I am horrible at these things and this is my first time attempting something like this. I have never really used command prompt before and I only learned how to open it today, so I really need help.

Comment: The error `File not found` indicates that you don't have a `D:\Downloads` folder. Are your downloads going to the root of `D:\ `?

Comment: Can you please explain to us, @Dan, how did you manage to achieve this goal: "_I accidentally made my downloads and my D:\ drive a single entity_"?

Comment: If CMD cannot find the folder whereas Explorer shows it, then open its security settings and make Administrators group the owner of this folder and all its sub-objects, apply, then set full security permissions to your account/group.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai I followed the steps on this website: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/moving-your-personal-data-folders-in-windows-vista-the-easy-way/ 

My objective was to store my folders in my D: drive.
I don't just want to cut and paste because when I go to "My pictures" it would still be from the C: drive.

The link I provided was helpful and I was successful when I tried it with "My Music" but I for "Downloads" I can't quite recall if followed the steps or I did it right from the "Favourites" tab on File Explorer.

Comment: @Worthwelle I always had a Downloads folder on my C: drive before I made his mistake. But I have been saving everything I download to my desktop for quite a while now. Even if I save a folder now it saves to my desktop.

Comment: @Akina It isn't on explorer either. 

When I go to my name under explorer with all the files, there is pictures, music, video etc. but what used to be my "Downloads" is now "Local Disk (D:)" and when I try to create a folder with the name "Downloads" it says "This destination already contains a folder named 'Downloads' "

Comment: What does the Edit Box inside the _Location_ Tab contains **now** for the `Downloads` Folder in its _Properties_ Window from the _File Explorer_ Static Software Application, @Dan? Can you also tell us what is the Output of the `SUBST` Command in a Command-Line Preprocessor?