# I accidentally changed "downloads" location to C:\ and can't change it back

Tags: windows-10, download

I accidentally changed the location of the "Downloads" folder to `C:\` and now my whole `C:` drive looks like the "Downloads" folder.

When I try to change the location it says "can't redirect a parent into a child".

What do I do?

Comment: Try the [registry method](https://superuser.com/a/1043626/8672).

Comment: Assuming the "Restore default" button doesn't work, If you have another drive, you could change the location to somewhere on that, and then you should be able to change it back to somewhere on drive C:.

Comment: Please get your accounts merged.   And then ask follow-up questions by editing your original question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Registry Editor
2. Navigate to:
   `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Using other paths you see there as an example, edit the paths for these two values to reflect the path to your desired `Downloads` folder:

`{7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4}`
`{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}`

[image]

That will fix the shortcut under `This PC`.

Locate a hidden, system file named `desktop.ini` in the root of your C: drive & delete it. That should rid you of the custom icon.

Answer (score 0):

@Gab - You said a System Restore worked for you. Here is a summary of actions required.

Go to Advanced System Properties. Select the System Protection tab.

Click on the System Restore button and Restore to the Prior Point.

This works like a giant UNDO button in the right circumstances.